# Array of hashes whose key is an array containing ranges

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, range

I need to map a number of IDs and ranges of IDs to single values. I would like to store the whole structure in one object.

Is the following a sensible way to do this? What is the best way to search the keys by a single integer value to return the corresponding value?

```
large array = [
   {[3110..3220, 10200, 43680] =>   'A0300'},
   {[5200, 7100..8990, 9100..9900] => 'B0400'},
   {[17110..18121, 20160, 2210..22290] => 'C0600'}
]
```

Comment: To look up keys by _what_? Single integer?

Comment: Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reasonable format to store the data would be a plain old simple hash:

```
input = { [3110..3220, 10200, 43680] =>  'A0300',
          [5200, 7100..8990, 9100..9900] => 'B0400',
          [17110..18121, 20160, 2210..22290] => 'C0600' }
```

To lookup the element one might use case-equal aka triple-equal. Luckily it’s implemented for integers as well:

```
value = 7300
result = input.detect { |k, _| k.any? { |r| r === value } }
result ? result.last : nil
#⇒ "B0400"
```

Comment: Good one, mudsie.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no need to separate each key-value pair into a different hash as you did. Furthermore, you are using the hash in a wrong way. A hash key-value need not be one-to-one. It is better to have something like this:

```
{
  3110..3220 => 'A0300',
  10200 => 'A0300',
  43680 => 'A0300',
  5200 => 'B0400',
  7100..8990 => 'B0400',
  9100..9900 => 'B0400',
  17110..18121 => 'C0600',
  20160 => 'C0600',
  2210..22290 => 'C0600',
}
```

But my guess is that you are actually asking a X-Y question, and my answer above is still not the best solution for you.

Comment: Of course, a hash can contain multiple key value pairs! thanks. I had this structure originally I just seemed that there was some repetition in that multile kay value pairs referred to the same value, thus my attempt to move the keys into a single array which pointed to a single value. Why is is the longer versions above a better solution, is it that there'one s less nesting level?

Comment: I could not disagree more. This violates DRY, but even more important that is makes it drastically hard to modify it. Reverse-lookup of the keys for the value is also becoming nuts.

Answer (score 1):

If the values were hardwired, one could use a case statement.

```
def look_it_up(n)
  case n
  when 7100..8990, 9100..9900, 5200
    'B0400'
  when 17110..18121, 22100..22290, 20160
    'C0600'
  when 3110..3220, 10200, 43680
    'A0300'
  else
    nil
  end
end

look_it_up 10200 #=> "A0300"
look_it_up  9135 #=> "B0400"
look_it_up 22100 #=> "C0600"
look_it_up  3079 #=> nil
```

Assuming `n` is somewhat uniformly distributed, I have, for reasons of efficiency, ordered the `when` clauses by decreasing numbers of numbers included, and within each `when` clause, I put the ranges first and ordered those ranges by decreasing size.

If the values are not necessarily hardwired, one could use `find/detect`, as @mudasobwa has done.

If many lookups were to be performed, I would suggest constructing a hash whose keys are integers.

```
def init_arr(*args)
  args.each do |*a, value|
    a.each do |e|
      if e.is_a?(Range)
        e.each { |n| @h[n] = value }
      else
        @h[e] = value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then for any `n`, `@h[n]` gives its value. For example,

```
@h = {}
init_arr [1..4, 8..10, 11, "cat"]
  @h #=> {1=>"cat", 2=>"cat", 3=>"cat", 4=>"cat", 8=>"cat", 9=>"cat",
     #    10=>"cat", 11=>"cat"}
init_arr [13..14, 7, "dog"]
  @h #=> {1=>"cat", 2=>"cat", 3=>"cat", 4=>"cat", 8=>"cat", 9=>"cat",
     #    10=>"cat", 11=>"cat", 13=>"dog", 14=>"dog", 7=>"dog"}
```

Then (say),

```
@h[13]
  #=> "dog"
@h[11]
  #=> "cat"
@h[12]
  #=> nil
```

Naturally, this assumes `@h.size` is manageable.

One could alternatively construct a look-up array, say `@arr`, which should be faster than using a hash (though it might consume much more memory than would a hash). `@arr[n]` would return the value for `n` or `nil` if there is no corresponding value. If some values were negative, or if the smallest `n` were quite large, one would instead write `@arr[n+@offset]`, where `@offset` is the obvious value.

Answer (score 0):

It is pointless to use arrays and/or ranges as hash key, when you want to look up the data given a single value. The advantage of a hash is that, given a key, you can find a value quickly. In your case, you would have to traverse the hash sequentially to find the entry. In this case, it would make more sense to use an arrays of pairs, the first component describing the range and the second component describing the ID.

If you want to use a hash, you should make a corresponding entry for each possible integer value.

If you know that the integer values can not be higher than a certain size, you could create a sparse array, where the integer value is the index position, and the ID is the content of the array cell. This is fastest, but of course takes up some space.